# Pass parameters to processhtml grunt task for updating index.html file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I am very new to grunt.I have two grunt tasks , one for deploying to dev and one for deploying to test. I wanted to pass the respective deployment url as pararmeter when running the tasks. Also i would like to use this passed parameter value to  be updated in my index.html by using `processhtml`

My deployment tasks:

```
grunt.registerTask('deploy-dev', ['msdeploy:target1', 'msdeploy:target2']);
grunt.registerTask('deploy-test', ['msdeploy:target3', 'msdeploy:target4']);
//I would like to pass my respective url parameters here , how ?
```

//how can i use the passed parameters above here to process the html ?

```
   processhtml: {
                options: {
                    data: {
                        message: grunt.template.today(),
                    }
                },
                dist: {
                    files: {
                        'dist/index.html': ['index.html']
                    }
                }
            }
```

Index.html:
//i wanted to use the dynamic url value from processhtml here to be updated

```
 <!-- build:template !-->
    <script>
        var deployUrl = '<%= url%>'
    </script>
    <!-- /build -->
```

Is there a better way of doing this ? If i am thinking the right way, how to do it ? Kindly help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
processhtml: {
                options: {
                    data: {
                        message: grunt.template.today(),
                        //this will be replaced dynamically based on
                        //deployment regions
                        serviceUrl: ''
                    }
                },
                dist: {
                    files: {
                        'dist/index.html': ['index.html']
                    }
                }
            }

 grunt.registerTask('deploy-dev', function () {
        grunt.config.set('processhtml.options.data.serviceUrl', "http://server1/api");
        //run the processhtml with the new parameter
        grunt.task.run('processhtml');
        //call the deployment task
        grunt.task.run('msdeploy:server1');
    });
```

Index.html file changes:

```
<!-- build:template !-->
    <script>
        var buildDateTime = '<%= message %>'
        var serviceBase = '<%= serviceUrl %>'
    </script>
<!-- /build -->
```